# Using SitePrism's page object elements to perform page assertions

Tags: rspec, automation, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

I want to know if there's a way to perform a `page.should` assertion with a page object element directly, instead of giving the xpath or CSS selector string as a parameter.

i.e.:

Page class:

```
class FooClass < SitePrism::Page
  element :action_select, '.autocomplete.medium'
end
```

Step definition:

```
page.should have_css('.autocomplete.medium')

#Sort of thing desired:

page.should have_css(action_select.get_css)
```

That `.get_css` does not exist but it's used to illustrate what's desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `element` method creates a `has_<element name>?` method that can check the existence of the element.

For example, for your page:

```
page.has_action_select?
#=> returns true if it exists, false if it doesn't
```

This allows your assertion to be:

```
page.should have_action_select
```

For more details, you can see the [site prism page](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism#testing-for-the-existence-of-the-element).

Comment: Great answer thanks Justin Ko and great info there Nat Ritmeyer!